# scaffolding viewmodels based on database tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, poco

Is there anything that would aid us in designing/scaffolding View models from SQL Server database tables but would result in very lean classes? I know something like that exists for Rails, maybe there's something similar in ASP.NET MVC?

I like what EF wizard creates but it's too heavy - too much attributes, constraints, events and everything is attached to the entities so you can't actually use them as View models (actually you can but it quickly becomes a pain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use a POCO generator for your EF4 model instead of the default one. This is a link explaining how. [LINK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx)
I hope you can adapt it to fill your needs.

A POCO Class(Plain Old CLR Objects) is by definition a lightweight class, that is (maybe) what you're looking for.

Comment: This is perfect, I was completely unaware of its existence.