# MVC ViewModel Scaffold Item

Tags: model-view-controller, viewmodel

I am using MVC 5 with entity framework 6. I have created some ViewModels and was wondering if you can use **Add Scaffold Item** to create the controller and views from the ViewModel. I am getting an error when I select the ViewModel when creating using **Add Scaffold Item**

Does anyone also have a good resource for creating ViewModels searches arent bringing up what im looking for. Basically I have a table which holds listings but I only want to display a few fields in the view from this table, is this possible and also using **Add Scaffold Item**?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to scaffold ViewModels myself but what error are you getting specifically?

Furthermore it seems there are possibilities of doing so, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771003/scaffolding-viewmodels-based-on-database-tables) and [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/).

You could also instead generate POCOs from your table and then Scaffold the controller and views for it. Then to display certain properties create a viewmodel and pass that in and around to your controller and view.

Here is a [link regarding viewmodels](http://rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp.net-mvc-applications), I hope it helps.

Comment: I ended up creating from model and editing thanks. I will look at scaffolding view models as it saves a lot of time